# Error : SQLiteLog: (1) no such column : nometprenom

Tags: java, xml, sqlite, android-sqlite

When I tried to execute "SearchPass", I got `SQLiteLog: (1) no such column` error in logcat. What's the error in my query please?

The Logcat:

```
06-02 13:33:17.168 2971-2971/com.example.pc.myapplication E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: nometprenom
06-02 13:33:17.169 2971-2971/com.example.pc.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.pc.myapplication, PID: 2971
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: nometprenom (code 1): , while compiling: select nometprenom , motdepasse fromcontacts
```

The searchPass method:

```
public String searchPass (String nometprenom) {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select nometprenom , motdepasse from"+TABlE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    String a,b;
    b= "not found";
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            a = cursor.getString(0);

            if (a.equals(nometprenom)) {
                b = cursor.getString(1);
                break;
            }
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            return b;
        }
```

The class contact.java:

```
public class Contact {
int id  ;
String nometprenom , motdepasse, cin ;
public void setId (int id) {
    this.id=id;
}
public int getId() {
    return this.id ;
}
public void setnometprenom (String nometprenom) {
    this.nometprenom=nometprenom;
}
public String getnometprenom () {
    return this.nometprenom ;
}
public void setcin (String cin) {
    this.cin=cin;
}
public String getcin () {
    return this.cin ;
}
public void setmotdepasse (String motdepasse) {
    this.motdepasse=motdepasse;
}
public String getmotdepasse () {
    return this.motdepasse ;
}
```

Comment: Add space before table name (after the `from`)

Comment: Notice the query executed `select nometprenom , motdepasse fromcontacts` - you see there is no space between `from` and `contacts`

Comment: the right query is : String query = "select nometprenom , motdepasse from " +TABlE_NAME;    Thanks @DanielM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the error:
`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: nometprenom (code 1): , while compiling: select nometprenom , motdepasse fromcontacts`

In the query there is no space between `from` and `contacts`. When building the query - add space after `from`, like this:

```
String query = "select nometprenom , motdepasse from "+TABlE_NAME;
```